# Quadratic-fractional or linear-fractional programming through SDP relaxation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-forms, semidefinite-programming, linear-fractional-transformation

I have an optimization problem as follows.

$$ \text{maximize}_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{P} \frac{(\mathbf{x}^{T} H_{p} \mathbf{x})}{(\mathbf{x}^{T} C_{p} \mathbf{x})}$$
$$s.t. A\mathbf{x}=b, F\mathbf{x} \le d, \textbf{x} \in \{0,1\}^{n}$$

The objective function is a sum of fractional functions of trace of quadratic form where $C_{p}$ is rank-1 PSD matrix. $H_{p}$ is a $n\times n$ size PSD matrix. All the variables and constants are on the real domain. $A$ and $F$ are $m_{1}\times n$ and $m_{2}\times n$ matrices, respectively.
I would like to get any suggestion or approaches to solve this problem.

---

My approach to solve this problem was using the SDP relaxation with introducing a new variable $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{xx}^{T}$. Then we have

$$ \text{maximize}_{\mathbf{Z}\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1 \times n+1}} \sum_{i=1}^{P} \frac{\text{Tr}(\hat{H}_{p} \mathbf{Z})}{\text{Tr}(\hat{C}_{p} \mathbf{Z})}$$
$$s.t. \text{Tr}(\hat{A}_{j}\mathbf{Z})=b_{j}, \text{Tr}(\hat{F}_{k}\mathbf{Z}) \le d_{k}, \text{Tr}(\hat{I}_{l}\mathbf{Z})=0$$
$$ \mathbf{Z}_{n+1,n+1}=1, \mathbf{Z} \succcurlyeq 0.$$

I just simplify the constraints for the new variable
$$
\mathbf{Z} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{x} \\
\mathbf{x}^{T} & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

All the matrices with $\hat{\cdot}$ (hat) notation is a $(n+1 \times n+1)$ size real symmetric matrix corresponding to the objective function and the constraints. For example,
$$
\hat{H}_{p} = \begin{bmatrix}
H_{p} & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
\hat{A}_{j} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{j}/2 \\
a^{T}_{j}/2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a_j$ is a $j$-th column of the matrix $A$ and $b_j$ is a $j$-th element of the vector $b$. We can do the same thing for the matrix $C_p$ and $F$.
Please note that the above matrix expressions are block matrix expressions. The boolean constraint can be replaced by $\text{Tr}(\hat{I}_{l}\mathbf{Z})=0$, for example,
$$
\hat{I}_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & -1/2 \\
0 & \ddots & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
-1/2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now the problem has an objective function of a sum of linear fractional-functions. The first 4 constraints are linear constraints and finally, without the rank-1 constraint, $\mathbf{Z}$ should be a PSD matrix.

At this moment, even the relaxed version of the problem looks hard to solve directly. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have any additional conditions on $H_p$ and $C_p$ besides the fact that they are real and symmetric? Also, why do you have traces involved? Those are quadratic forms, hence scalar. You have also not defined most of the matrices in your relaxed problem. Please define all the matrices correctly to make your post clearer.

Comment: @KBS I have added the conditions and definitions, Thanks!